# Inserting figure inside table cell align issue

Tags: tables, includegraphics, acmart

I would like to insert a small figure inside a column cell but it misaligns with the rest of the text and creates an empty extra space per each row. Is it possible to avoid this behaviour ?

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[tb]
\caption{Example Table with Figure}

\begin{tabular}{lllllccc}
\toprule
\textbf{ColA} &  \textbf{Description} & Text & Col & Col & Col &  Fig & \textbf{Val} \\
\midrule

Test  & Explanation & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \includegraphics{figures/fig-tiny.eps}& Val  \\\addlinespace
Test  & Explanation & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \includegraphics{figures/fig-tiny.eps}& Val  \\\addlinespace
\bottomrule


\end{tabular}
\end{table*}


\begin{table*}[tb]
\caption{Example Table without Figure}

\begin{tabular}{lllllccc}
\toprule
\textbf{ColA} &  \textbf{Description} & Text & Col & Col & Col &  Fig & \textbf{Val} \\
\midrule

Test  & Explanation & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & Val & Val  \\\addlinespace
Test  & Explanation & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & Val & Val  \\\addlinespace
\bottomrule


\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How could I get rid of the vertical misaligment and also the extra space inserted between the rows ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Thanks for giving an MWE!

Comment: The image (not a figure environment)  is placed just like a "m" character, but the size matter. You will obtain the same result with a big "m".  Of course, assuming that there are not blank margins inside the image.  Obviously, this also matter. If you reduce the height of a image without any kind of margins to 1ex,  you will see that is perfectly aligned with "4" and "Val",  but not with the bottom of characters with descenders like "p".

Comment: @Fran yes that worked, when I set the height to 3ex it is readable and the vertical space is way better from the original so this version worked `\includegraphics[height=3ex]{figures/fig-tiny.eps}`